# Flutter DateTime , Open Close if

Tags: datetime, flutter

I want to show between 09:00 am - 20:00 pm widget, other time another widget so
for example now 13:00 my shop open I want to show open my shop.

thanks

```
openSaat() {
  return Container(
    width: 170,
    height: 40,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          radius: 12,
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 5,),
        Text("Open Now",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white),)
      ],
    ),
  );
}

closeSaat() {
  return Container(
    width: 170,
    height: 40,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
    child: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            radius: 12,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 5,),
          Text("Close Now",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white),)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    body: currentWidget()
    );
  }
  static DateTime now = DateTime.now();

   Widget currentWidget() {
    var hours = now.hour;

    if (hours >= 09 && hours < 21) {
      return _openSaat();
    } else
      return _closeSaat();
  }



Widget _openSaat() {
  return Container(
    width: 170,
    height: 40,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          radius: 12,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Text(
          "Open Now",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget _closeSaat() {
  return Container(
    width: 170,
    height: 40,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
    child: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            radius: 12,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            "Close Now",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You should be careful to do this with `DateTime.utc` rather than `DateTime.now`, and adjust your range appropriately.  Otherwise, it's using the local time, and not reflecting your real-world hours.

Comment: Hi, this work fine, but how can i add in code that on thuesday show always closed? Thank you